# Restricting the use of an assembly from assemblies that are not signed

Tags: c#, .net

I have a requirement to have a restriction in an assembly such that only assemblies that are signed with a given key can use it. I am inexperienced, but what I understand is signing is done to help identify who created the assembly. Hence, just signing this assembly should not be enough to ensure that all calling assemblies are signed. Probably the reverse is true, i.e. if an assembly is signed, all the assemblies it depends on should be signed(by the same key perhaps). What would be the way to meet the requirement?

Comment: Do you mean something like this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2004/06/07/150378.aspx ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [PublisherIdentityPermissionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.publisheridentitypermissionattribute.aspx).

If you apply PublisherIdentityPermissionAttribute to MyClass class then only classes in assemblies signed by the `mycert.cer` certificate can use your class. You need to put `SecurityAction.Demand`

> All callers higher in the call stack are required to have been granted
>   the permission specified by the current permission object

Use like

```
[PublisherIdentityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, CertFile = "mycert.cer")]
public class MyClass
```

You can also use it on assembly level to protect entire assembly (however assembly level security will not work since .Net 4.0 unless you set `<NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>` in configuration).

Comment: Please don't just reply with a link. Give some explanation and an example of how to use it to solve OP's problem.